# How to sort a Firemonkey Treeview?

Tags: delphi, sorting, treeview, firemonkey

with this function it is possible to sort Items in different FMX components:

```
function(Right, Left: TFmxObject): Integer;
```

This worked for me with a ListBox, but I can't figure out how to sort a TreeView.

```
function SortText(Left, Right: TFMXObject): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareText((Left as TTreeViewItem).Text, (Right as TTreeViewItem).Text);
end;
```

This doesn't work, but I don't know why.

Comment: Use the [`Sorted`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.TreeView.TCustomTreeView.Sorted) property and optionally write your own comparer in the [`OnCompare`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.TreeView.TCustomTreeView.OnCompare) event (optionally, since by default nodes are sorted alphabetically, based on their labels, which is what your current comparer does).

Comment: Somehow that doesn't seem to work for me. If I set sorted to 'True', nothing happens. My TreeView has multiple Childs which have multile childs again. But they aren't sorted...

Comment: Yeah, it sorts only top level nodes. But that's the nature of the internally called `TFmxObject.Sort` method. It sorts only immediate child objects.

Comment: I think that to sort all levels you will need [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/nUZJ7gyD) (at least in Delphi XE3).

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly for me :) I worked one something similar, but still messed around with the TreeView.Sort() function. Would you mind to post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it and others see it better?